# service command fails silently

Tags: command-line, server

I am on Ubuntu Server 14.04 and I followed the instructions [here](http://janvanoverveld.blogspot.in/2015/04/installation-apache-active-mq-on-ubuntu.html) to setup Apache ActiveMQ (5.13.3). However since activemq was not starting on boot I issued the command `sudo update-rc.d activemq defaults` and this seemed to work fine. However today I created another image doing exactly the same as above but now activemq is not starting on boot.

The root cause seems to be that issuing `sudo service activemq <command>` simply fails silently. However if I do `sudo /etc/init.d/activemq <command>` I am able to start/stop/status all fine.

I am at a loss as to why the `service` command is failing - any way I can debug this?